# Функция для конвертации байтов в другие единицы измерения

Tags: php

В зависимости от кол-ва байт подбирает максимально допустимую величину

```
function bytesConverting($bytes)
{
    $s = ['байт', 'Кбайт', 'Мбайт', 'Гбайт', 'Тбайт', 'Пбайт'];
    $e = floor(log($bytes)/log(1024));

    return sprintf('%.2f ' . $s[$e], ($bytes/pow(1024, floor($e))));
}
```

Как обстоят дела с точки зрения алгебры, можно ли упростить\изменить\имеете лучший вариант?

Comment: Нет ограничения на верхний предел, 1024 петабайта свалятся в ошибку. Куда уж упрощать - не знаю.

Comment: подстрока "байт" повторяется в каждом значении.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько замечаний:

1. «петабайт» или «ПБ» и прочие приведённые в вопросе приставки [относятся к степеням 10](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82), а не 2. Поэтому делить на 1000, а не 1024;
2. вы берете *натуральный* логарифм оператором php [`log()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.log.php) (по основанию *e*), а надо, наверное, по основанию 10: `log($bytes, 10)`;
3. как верно заметил [@Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki), не предусмотрены случаи выхода за пределы ожидаемых значений – как в бОльшую сторону, так и в минус (а то и строку по ошибке пришлют);
4. приставка "байт" присутствует во всех вариантах – почему бы её не вынести из массива `["", "К", "М", ..]`, и приписывать один раз результату?
5. не проверял, но, вероятно, логарифмы считаются чуть дольше, чем простое сравнение чисел. Тогда быстрее будет код с каскадом `if .. else if` для каждого диапазона.